# How can I scrape all the images from a website?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a website where I'd like to get all the images from the [website](https://www.mcmaster.com/).

The website is kind of a dynamic in nature, I tried using google's Agenty Chrome extension and followed the steps:

- I Choose one image that I want to extract using CSS selector, this will make the extension select the same other images automatically.
- Viewed the Show button and select ATTR(attribute).
- Changed src as an ATTR field.
- Gave a name field name option.
- Saved it & ran it in using Agenty platform/API.

This should yield me the result but it's not, it is returning an empty output.

Is there any better option? Will BS4 a better option for this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As I have mentioned in my question, I haven't done any coding for this. I used a google extention (name mentioned above) to get the result.

Comment: My bad for not seeing that. Sorry.

Comment: Not a problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to download all images in the website. It is actually very easy to do this effectively using beautiful soup 4 (BS4).

```
#code to find all images in a given webpage

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import requests
import shutil

url=('https://www.mcmaster.com/')
html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, features="lxml")
for img in soup.findAll('img'):
    assa=(img.get('src'))
new_image=(url+assa)
```

You can also download the image with this tacked-on to the end:

```
response = requests.get(my_url, stream=True)
with open('Mypic.bmp', 'wb') as file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, file)
```

Everything in two lines:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup; import urllib.request; from urllib.request import urlretrieve
for img in (BeautifulSoup((urllib.request.urlopen("https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html")), features="lxml")).findAll('img'): assa=(img.get('src')); urlretrieve(("https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/"+assa), "Mypic.bmp")
```

The new image should be in the same directory as the python file, but can be moved with:

```
os.rename()
```

In the case of the McMaster website, the images are linked differently, so the above methods won't work. The following code should get most of the images on the website:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re
import urllib.request
import shutil
import requests
req = Request("https://www.mcmaster.com/")
html_page = urlopen(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")

links = []

for link in soup.findAll('link'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

print(links)
```

UPDATE: I found from some github post the below code that is MUCH more accurate:

```
import requests
import re
image_link_home=("https://images1.mcmaster.com/init/gfx/home/.*[0-9]")
html_page = requests.get(('https://www.mcmaster.com/'),headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.108 Safari/537.36'}).text
for item in re.findall(image_link_home,html_page):
    if str(item).startswith('http') and len(item) < 150:
        print(item.strip())
    else:
        for elements in item.split('background-image:url('):
            for item in re.findall(image_link_home,elements):
                print((str(item).split('")')[0]).strip())
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! 

Many thanks for your response! This is a kind of solution that I tried however I ran your exact code and I only got this below response:

'https://www.mcmaster.com/https://images1.mcmaster.com/init/gfx/MastheadLogo.svg?ver=1545146094'

Which means it is only giving me the headline of the website. Also, the image that I am storing is resulting in an invalid image. 

This website is very different than normal other sites, hence I'm getting a lot of issues. Hence, I tried with an extension. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Hello, I tested the code on the apod.nasa.gov website and it worked. The code finds any links in the html source with the <IMG src=""> tag, which the mcmaster site doesn't use - it uses regular links. I updated my answer to get most of the images in the website. Feel free to upvote it if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html), it makes the crawling seamless, by selecting the content you wish to download with **css tags** You can automate the crawling easily.

Answer (score 0):

This site using CSS embedding to store images. If you check the source code you can find links which has **https://images1.mcmaster.com/init/gfx/home/** those are the actual images but its actually stitched together (row of images)

Example : https://images1.mcmaster.com/init/gfx/home/Fastening-and-Joining-Fasteners-sprite-60.png?ver=1539608820

```
import requests
import re
url=('https://www.mcmaster.com/')
image_urls = []
html_page = requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.108 Safari/537.36'}).text
for values in re.findall('https://images1.mcmaster.com/init/gfx/home/.*[0-9]',html_page):
    if str(values).startswith('http') and len(values) < 150:
        image_urls.append(values.strip())
    else:
        for elements in values.split('background-image:url('):
            for urls in re.findall('https://images1.mcmaster.com/init/gfx/home/.*[0-9]',elements):
                urls = str(urls).split('")')[0]
                image_urls.append(urls.strip())
print(len(image_urls))
print(image_urls)
```

**Note:** **Scraping** website is subject to copyrights

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Agenty Web Scraping Tool](https://www.agenty.com/products/scraping-agent/).

1. Setup your scraper using Chrome extension to extract `src` attribute from images
2. Save the agent to run on cloud.

Here is similar question answered on Agenty forum - https://forum.agenty.com/t/can-i-extract-images-from-website/24

[image: images scraping]

**Full Disclosure** - I am working at Agenty